# Is there a way to add issues to a github forked repo (without modifying the original)?

Tags: github

I notice there's no "issues" tab on my forked github repo. Is there a way to allow me to fork a repo, but still add issues/wiki/etc?

Comment: This question is a duplicate of http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/179468/forking-a-repo-on-github-but-allowing-new-issues-on-the-fork. why it's not closed yet ?

Comment: @Abhisek This question is _not closed yet_, and should not be closed, for two reasons: 1) the "dupe" is on another site, and 2) the "dupe" is closed itself, and therefore subject to removal. If the other question was deleted, or the site closed, we would then have a question closed as a dupe of a non-existent question and a dead link.

Answer (score 186, accepted):

- Fork a repo
- Go to the Settings page of your fork.
- Click 'General' tab on the left
- Scroll down to the Features subsection
- Tick the Issues checkbox

[image: Settings, General, Features]

Comment: What if you want to write an issue on someone else's fork?

Comment: @Pacerier Then you have to ask the owner to enable issues in their repository somehow.

Comment: @Pacerier As a workaround you can fork their repo and send a pull request - this allows you to write a comment.  Can all be done in the github UI.

Comment: This is incredible. Why am I looking for help instead of reading?

Comment: Issues is found under Feature

Comment: As of today, there is no "General" tab on the left.  What do I do?

Comment: @JayImerman send a picture, as on my side there is still a `General` tab.